# [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint must contain a first layout item'

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

i added this piece of code in viewdidload method to Add the Vertical Space Constraint to the top-most view

as based on apple **Technical Q&A QA1797
Preventing the Status Bar from Covering Your Views**

```
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.toolbar1
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0.0];
```

but it crashes app and shows this error  **NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint must contain a first layout item'**

Any clues why i m getting this error and how this can be fixed.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is self.toolbar1 nil?

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs if both items are nil. Most likely your first item 'self.toolbar1' is nil.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are setting up UI code in your init method, when your views are not created yet. Try moving your code to the viewDidLoad method and see if it works.